# R function to find difference in mean greater than or equal to a specific number

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, t-test

I have just started my basic statistic course using R and we're studying using R for paired t-tests. I have come across questions where we're given two sets of data and we're asked to find whether the difference in mean is equal to 0 or greater than 0 so on so forth. The function we use for two samples x and y with an unknown variance is similar to the one below;

```
t.test(x, y, var.equal=TRUE, alternative="greater")
```

My question is, how would we to do this if we wanted to test the difference in mean is more than or equal to a specified number against the alternative that its less than a specific number and not 0.

For example, say we're given two datas for before and after weights of 10 people. How do we test that the mean difference in weight is more than or equal to say 3kg against the alternative where the mean difference in weight is less than 3kg. Is there a way to do this? Would really appreciate any guidance on this matter.

Comment: From the documentation, argument `mu 
a number indicating the true value of the mean (or difference in means if you are performing a two sample test).`

Comment: @user2974951 so its something like, t.test(x , y , paired = TRUE, alternative = "less", mu = 3, conf.level = 0.95) for paired data at 5%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify `alternative= "greater"` in the function `t.test()` plus the  mean you want to test `mu=`. There is also other options as "lower" or the default "two.sided". See the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/t.test).